# Does the order of variables and functions matter in Class (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, order-of-execution

When defining variables and functions within a class in python 3.x does it matter in which order you define variables and functions?

Is class code pre-complied before you would call the class in main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of class attributes does not matter except in specific cases (e.g. properties when using decorator notation for the accessors). The class object itself will be instantiated once the `class` block has exited.

Comment: _"The class object itself will be instantiated once the class block has exited"_ Isn't the class object instantiated when the `class` statement is encountered -- but _bound_ to the class name only on exit of the statement ?

Comment: Thanks , Thats what i thought , just wanted to make sure. thanks for clearing it up

Comment: @SylvainLeroux The class block is executed with some namespace (a dict-like object provided by the metaclass) to collect class members, then the populated namespace is passed to the metaclass to create the actual class object. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation

Answer (score 3):

By default, all names defined in the block of code right within the `class` statement become keys in a `dict` (that's passed to the metaclass to actually instantiate the class when said block is all done).  In Python 3 you can change that (the metaclass can tell Python to use another mapping, such as an `OrderedDict`, if it needs to make definition order significant), but that's **not** the default.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter in which order variables and functions are defined in **Class** in **Python**.

For example, there is **"Text" class** as shown below then it works properly displaying **"Hello World"**:

```py
class Text:
    text1 = "Hello"
    
    def __init__(self, text2):
        self.text2 = text2            
   
    def helloWorld(self):
        return self.text1 + " " + self.text2
       
    def display(self):    
        print(self.helloWorld())
        
text = Text("World")
text.display() # "Hello World" is displayed
```

Next, I turned the class attributes upside down as shown below then it still works properly displaying **"Hello World"**:

```py
class Text:
    def display(self):    
        print(self.helloWorld())
   
    def helloWorld(self):
        return self.text1 + " " + self.text2
        
    def __init__(self, text2):
        self.text2 = text2
        
    text1 = "Hello"
        
text = Text("World")
text.display() # "Hello World" is displayed
```